# show only first element from a type with acf

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

i want to show only the first element of the 
"type" and not all elements which have the type "payment-services". How can i do that? Hope somebody can help me...

```
<?php if( have_rows('events', 4127) ):
                    while ( have_rows('events', 4127) ) : the_row();

                        $types = get_sub_field('type');

                        foreach($types as $type) {
                            if ($type == "payment-services") { ?> 



                        <div class="item-<?php foreach($types as $type ): echo $type; echo ' ' ; endforeach; ?>">
                            <img class="events-images" src="<?php the_sub_field('image', 4127); ?>" alt="">
                            <h2 class="events-title"><?php the_sub_field('title', 4127); ?></h2>
                            <p class="events-date"><?php the_sub_field('date', 4127); ?></p>
                            <p class="events-location"><?php the_sub_field('location', 4127); ?></p>
                            <a class="events-url btn" href="<?php the_sub_field('url', 4127); ?>"><?php the_sub_field('url_text'); ?></a>
                        </div>

                         <?php break; ?>
                    <?php }
                        }
                endwhile;
            endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly, you want the whole code inside `if ($type == "payment-services")` to run only once.
There might be an easier way to do this, but a suggestion is:

1. Add a variable with a certain value before your for loop (e.g. $run="yes")
2. Put the code you only want to run the first time inside an *if* statement, where it only runs if the above variable has its initial value
3. Change the value of the variable during the first iteration so the whole *if* statement is false during the rest of the loop.

So your code could look something like this:

```
....
$run="yes";
foreach($types as $type) {
  if($run=="yes"){
    if ($type == "payment-services") { 

      rest of code which will only run once

      $run="no";
    }       
  }
}
....
```